# Stripping white space and \n from a string of text

Tags: regex, ruby, string

I am working on a CLI scraper app that scrapes imdb for local movie listings based on a users zipcode.

I don't want to dive too deep in the code, but during one of the scrapes I am scraping for the address of the movie theater.

```
theater_address = theater.css('.address').text
```

When I use `binding.pry` and call the `theater_address` variable I receive the follwing back.

```
\n\n        2175 El Mercado Loop,\n        Sierra Vista\n        AZ\n        85635\n            | (520) 458-1936    \n \n"
```

I would like to have only the address get returned. The address should be a string that only says `2175 El Mercado Loop, Sierra Vista AZ 85650`

I don't want the phone number or any of the `\n` before, after, or throughout the text. I have tried `.chomp` and `.strip` but have a feeling it is more involved that that. Can anyone offer a suggestion here to get the address variable the way I want it?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried `.chomp` and `.strip` but have a feeling it is more involved that that. Can anyone offer a suggestion here to get the address variable the way I want it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the part you need is before the pipe `|`, you can try something like this:

```
s = "\n\n 2175 El Mercado Loop,\n Sierra Vista\n AZ\n 85635\n | (520) 458-1936 \n \n"
s.gsub(/\|.*$/,'').gsub(/\s{2,}/, ' ').strip
```

Explanation:

- remove everything between `|` and a newline with `gsub(/\|.*$/,'')`
- replace repeated whitespaces (including newlines) with a single space with `gsub(/\s{2,}/, ' ')`
- strip leading/trailing spaces with `strip`

Comment: That did the job! Thanks! I was playing around with `.gsub` while waiting on a response. I am still soooo confused with regex so I was starting to have a few issues there as well... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    (?:                 # begin a non-capture group
      \n\n[ ]+          # match string
      |                 # or
      \n[ ]+            # match string
      (?=[ ]\p{L})      # match a space and letter in a positive lookahead
      |                 # or
      \n[ ]+            # match string
      (?=[ ]\d{5})      # match a space and digits in a positive lookahead
      |                 # or
      \n.+\(\d{3}\).+\z # match string at end of string
    )                   # end non-capture group
    /xm                 # free-spacing regex definition and multiline modes
```

```
str.gsub(r,'')
  #=> "2175 El Mercado Loop, Sierra Vista AZ 85635"
```

The regular expression is conventionally written as follows:

```
/(?:\n\n +|\n +(?= \p{L})|\n +(?= \d{5})|\n.+\(\d{3}\).+\z)/m
```

The multiline option (`/m`) is needed because of the multiple newline characters after the newline following the zip code. This causes newline characters to be matched by `.`.

When written in free-spacing mode spaces are removed before the expression is parsed. They must therefore be protected. I have chosen to put each space in a character class (`[ ]`). One could alternatively escape the space (`\`), use Unicode `[[:space:]]` or `\p{Space}`. `\s` could be used, but it includes newline and other characters, so I avoid using it when only spaces are to be matched.